# Returning a ProvidedType from a static ProvidedMethod

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have a ProvidedType, `foo`, that is represented internally as a `Map<string,obj>`. There are some provided properties on this type which should return the value of members from the dictionary.

I want to return an instance of this providedtype from a static method on another provided type. I assumed I could do this simply by returning an instance of the map:

```
    let m =
      ProvidedMethod(nm, [], foo, IsStaticMethod = true)

    m.InvokeCode <- fun args ->
      <@@

        [|
          "foo", box "abc"
          "bar", box 123
        |] |> Map

      @@>
```

However when GetterCode gets triggered on `foo`, the argument is an empty object rather than my map:

```
          prop.GetterCode <- fun args ->
            <@@
              let fieldmap = (%%(args.[0]) : Map<string,obj>) // This fails because args.[0] is Object rather than a map.
              fieldmap.[fieldName]
            @@>
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "represented internally as a `Map<string,obj>`".  If you mean that the provided type's base type is `Map<string,obj>` then what you have should work as-is.  On the other hand, if you mean that the base type is `obj` but that you maintain the invariant that this is a `Map<string,obj>` at runtime, then you'll need to insert a cast into your quotation:

```
<@@
    let fieldmap = ((%%(args.[0]) : obj) :?> Map<string,obj>)
    fieldmap.[fieldName]
@@>
```

Comment: Thanks, turned out to be a typo. I'd put the base type on the wrong providedtype :P